# Server-side bind() function, immlib

Tags: python, immunity-debugger

How do I get IP address and port number out of bind function in Server application. Can it be achieved with hooks like bphook in immunity debugger?

My problem is that I don't know how to unpack struct psockaddr/sockaddr or how sockaddr is saved on the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume you are talking about Windows Sockets and IPv4, since you have not mentioned otherwise. `sockaddr` is very well described in [MSDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cNC8.png). It is defined as for IPv4 as follows:

```
struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};

struct sockaddr_in {
        short   sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct  in_addr sin_addr;
        char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

I will use simple server application for demonstration purposes. Firstly let's set breakpoint on `bind()` and see what stack looks like:

[image]

As you can see, `pSockAddr` is a pointer to `sockaddr` structure is pushed on to stack as a second argument to the function. Let's go a little further and examine the `sockaddr` at `0x0031F840`:

[image]

One very important thing to note is that `sin_port` and `sin_addr` are stored using [*big-endian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order, meaning the most significant part stored first.

Now let's jump in and get [pyCommand](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/01/26/starting-to-write-immunity-debugger-pycommands-my-cheatsheet/) created in order to automate it with [Immunity Debugger](http://www.immunityinc.com/products-immdbg.shtml). For this purpose I will use `BpHook`:

```
# bindtrace PyCommand by PSS 

from immlib import *

NAME = "bindtrace"

class BindBpHook(BpHook):
    def __init__(self):
        BpHook.__init__(self)

    def run(self, regs):
        imm = Debugger()

        imm.log(" ")
        imm.log("Bind() called:")

        # Read sockaddr structure address
        sockaddr = imm.readLong(regs["ESP"] + 8)        

        # Read 2 bytes of sin_family member
        sockaddr_sin_family = imm.readShort(sockaddr)

        # Read 2 bytes of sin_port and calculate port number 
        # since it is stored as big-endian
        portHiByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 2, 1))
        portLowByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 3, 1))
        sockaddr_sin_port = portHiByte * 256 + portLowByte

        # Read 4 bytes of sin_addr since it is stored as big-endian
        ipFirstByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 4, 1))
        ipSecondByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 5, 1))
        ipThirdByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 6, 1))
        ipForthByte = ord(imm.readMemory(sockaddr + 7, 1))

        # Print results to Log View window
        imm.log("---> Pointer to sockaddr structure: 0x%08x" % sockaddr)
        imm.log("---> sockaddr.sin_family: %d" % sockaddr_sin_family)
        imm.log("---> sockaddr.sin_port: %d" % sockaddr_sin_port)
        imm.log("---> sockaddr.sin_addr: %d.%d.%d.%d" % \
                        (ipFirstByte,ipSecondByte,ipThirdByte,ipForthByte))
        imm.log(" ")
        imm.log("Press F9 to resume")


def main(args):

    imm = Debugger()
    functionToHook = "ws2_32.bind"

    # Find address of the function to hook
    functionAddress = imm.getAddress(functionToHook)

    # Create and install our hook
    myHook = BindBpHook()
    myHook.add(functionToHook, functionAddress)

    imm.log("Hook for %s installed at: 0x%08x" % (functionToHook, functionAddress))

    return "[*] Hook installed."
```

Installation of the script is very simple. All pyCommands are stored in ./pyCommands folder of Immunity Debugger installation. I named my file `bindtrace.py`.

Thereafter, we load our executable into Immunity Debugger. Debugger will break automatically at entry point. Right after that we invoke the above pyCommand by typing `!bindtrace`, and run the executable by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>. As soon as breakpoint hits, we get the result in Log windows, which can be accessed through <kbd>Alt + L</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: cool explanation.